# Integral in case of functions defined by two expressions in two parts of the real line

Tags: calculus

Consider two functions $F$ and $f$ defined by
$$F(x)=\begin{cases} x^2 &\text{if }\,0 \leq x \leq 1\\\\
         1&\text{if }\,    x > 1 
\end{cases}
        $$
and the function $f$ given by $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}2x & \text{if }\,0\leq x\leq 1\\ \, 0&\text{else} \end{cases}$$
I want to know how for a given parameter $t>0$, the following integral can be calculated :$$ \int_0^1 f(x) f(x+t)[F(x+t)-F(x)]^{2} dx$$

Comment: If $t>1$ then $f(x+t)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f(x+t)$ becomes zero when $x + t > 1$, and the whole integral becomes zero.

Hence you need to split the integral, depending on when $x + t \le 1$ and $x + t > 1$.

Explicitly:
$$\int_0^1 f(x)f(x+t)[F(x+t)-F(x)]^2dx = \int_0^{\max \{1-t, 0\}} f(x)f(x+t)[F(x+t)-F(x)]^2dx$$

Since $x+t\le1$, we can use the definitions of $f, F$ accordingly.